# Ruby - separating excel data contained in one column into individual columns

Tags: regex, ruby, csv

I'm trying to use Ruby to manipulate some excel data, but the .csv files I'm given have all of the data in one column.

The data has the headers and values separated by commas, but they are contained within the first column. *Also, some of the values within the first column have text surrounded by quotes with commas inside the quotes.*

Is there a way to separate the data within the first column into separate columns with Ruby?

I know you can do this in an excel, but I'd like to be able to do this in Ruby so I don't have to correct every .csv file manually.

I've included an example of the .csv file below.

[image]

The desired output would be:

```
{:header 1 => integer,
:header 2 => text,
:header 3 => "this text, has a comma within the quote"
:header 4 => integer}
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one crude way to do it:

```
require 'csv'                                                                                                                                           
result = []                                                                       

csv = CSV.read('./file.csv')                                                      
headers = csv.shift                                                               
csv.each do |l|                                                                   
  hash = {}                                                                       
  hash[headers[0]] = l[0]                                                         
  hash[headers[1]] = l[1]                                                         
  hash[headers[2]] = l[2]                                                         
  hash[headers[3]] = l[3]                                                         
  result << hash                                                                  
end                                                                               

p result

[{"header 1"=>"integer",
  "header 2"=>"text",
  "header 3"=>"this text, has a comma within the quote",
  "header 4"=>"integer"},
 {"header 1"=>"integer",
  "header 2"=>"text",
  "header 3"=>"this text, has a comma within the quote",
  "header 4"=>"integer"}]
```

This of course assumes that every row has 4 values.

Edit: Here is an example of actually writing the result to a file:

```
CSV.open('./output.csv', 'wb') do |csv|                                           
  result.each do |hash|                                                           
    temp = []                                                                     
    hash.each do |key, value|                                                     
      temp << "#{key} => #{value}"                                                
    end                                                                           
  csv << temp                                                                   
  end                                                                             
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting an output with an array of hashes, but the key value pairs are:  

[{row 1 => row 2}, {row 1 => row 3}] I'm still having trouble creating columns. Any other ideas?

Comment: I also just checked and it looks like because the .csv file has the data in one column, everything inside that column(the first row in this case) is surrounded by quotes: ["header 1, header 2, header 3, header 4"] which is why it's having trouble associating the individual values and just linking to the row beneath.